# Simple (feature-light) wiki software with namespace support

Tags: wiki

I'm not absolutely certain whether this should be here or on Web Applications, but here goes.

I need wiki software, preferably something that runs on PHP but this is not a hard requirement, which supports namespaces.  That is, I need to be able to give users an arbitrary number of wiki spaces that do not overlap or interact with each other.  FOSS is preferred as well.

I've been unable to find something like this so far, so I may have to roll my own solution.  Does anyone know of such an application?

Comment: You can't do this with MediaWiki? (http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)

Comment: hrng.  was absolutely certain that MediaWiki couldn't, and it looks like you're right - it does support namespaces.  Feel free to convert your comment to a question and I'll accept it.

Comment: We have this in Confluence and I *HATE* it. Building separate gardens in an organisation builds walls where there shouldn't be any. Wikipedia became what it is through allowing open (and responsible) contributions. I'd recommend you seriously consider the end result of the separation you seek.

Comment: If I was building something for a corporate intranet, I'd be able to discuss that point with you, Bernhard.  However, in this case what I'm actually doing is far closer to a wikifarm than anything else.  I mean, it isn't a wikifarm, but users aren't going to be *unified in purpose* beyond their immediate circle of friends so a single namespace doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you consider [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) for this. It is PHP-based FOSS software.

[A search on the MediaWiki page reveals these results regarding Namespaces](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Namespace).

Answer (score 0):

It's not FOSS, but [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) will do this for you.